# c# -How to make a condition out of the selected listbox item?

Tags: c#, loops, user-interface, listbox

soooo this is my first time using the GUI

I'm making one based on a normal console code,

uk it's like I'm making a GUI for this code ( i made it first on console and now I'm moving it to GUI)

and I'm trying to move items from listbox1 to listbox2 based on a condition as in (if loop)

so what I want is when the user press the button all the succeeded student will get moved to listbox2

I tried so hard but I couldn't make it...

can u guys help me plz

```
public partial class FSS : Form
{
    private void FSS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    string Content = "";

    public FSS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "TXT|*.txt";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                Content = sr.ReadLine();
                if (Content != null)
                {

                    listBox1.Items.Add(Content);
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
        }            
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  You talk about a loop and moving something but none of that is apparent in your code

Comment: You can simply start by doing it in Console. Instead of using a StreamReader, you could get all the lines into an array using File.ReadAllLines() (after all you are using Listbox, so considerably line count is not much) and set that as source of listbox1. Then whatever your criteria is, you can also apply it to that array and set it as Listbox2's datasource. (using Console you can test yourself if you are getting items correctly. Rest is as simple as .DataSource = sourceCollection.

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp  yes dude ik u cant see it in my code, its cuz i dont know how to do it , and it is the same reason im asking here